# can i get Kibana version when all i have is URL of Kibana (without port number)?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, version, kibana

can i get Kibana version (from python as an example or command-line)?
,when All i have is URL of Kibana (without port number).

is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ideas to clarify your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
HTTP GET http://<host>:<port>/api/status
```

Something like

```
import requests

version = requests.get('http://<host>:<port>/api/status').json()['version']['number']
```

Comment: i mean when i don't have the port number, just link to Kibana

Comment: Try 5601 which is the default port

Comment: that means that there is no way to do that if i didn't have the port number ?